# Counter variable not working Asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a method to check if the `id` exists in a table and if it does insert into another database table; additionally I have label that will display the number of data entered. The query to insert into the database and select from the database works fine; but my problem is I'm not able to `count`, only receiving a count of 1 at all times. It is not incrementing; my question how do I get the counter to increment rather than just showing 1 at all times. This is what I have so far

```
protected void btnComplete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = txtid.Text;     
    string user = lblUsername.Text;      
    string date = lblDate.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ToString());

    //commands identifying the stored procedure
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectId", conn);

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("CreateUserId", con);

    // execute the stored procedures
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id);


    conn.Open();


    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows) 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = barcode);

                 cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = user;
                 cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
                 counter = counter + 1;

            }

           reader.Close();
           cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();


           lblCount.Text = counter.ToString();
        }
        else
        {

            lblError.Text = barcode + " does not exist!!";
        }


    }
```

Comment: That `counter` is probably a field in your page class? Every request (and a postback is also a new request) is handled by a fresh instance of that page class - so fields are re-initialized.

Comment: yes counter is field; how do i handle it differently

Comment: If you want values to survive between requests, store them in Session

Comment: can you show me an example

Comment: @HansKesting; thanks for your help; appreciated it pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you are asked for `stored procedures` and before giving you a concrete answer, you should fix some problems in your code

1) use `using{}` blocks with `command` and `connection` to make sure they are disposed.

2) In `while` loop, you are adding parameters to `cmd1`. Think what will happen if `while` loop runs more than 1 time!!

Now, if you want to show `max` in counter, just get `max` from database !!

> In your `cmd` object you are sending some `ID` to stored procedure. It will always return 1 record if id is unique in your table.

So your counter is always 1

**Solution**

Not modifying much of your code, add `count(id) as counter` in your storedprocedure query returning result of cmd. 
And in the `while` loop assign that to counter variable.

```
counter = Convert.ToInteger(reader[“counter”].ToString());
```

> Above is not best solution though. As it will `count` records for all rows and will reduce performance over time.

For best solution, you need to make another `command` object that executes a query like `select count(id) from YourTableName`

This will give you number of records in your table.

**Edit**

From your comment. 
You only want total records after inserting from cmd1. 
Just do following:

1) In your storedProcedure for cmd 1, write `Select Isnull(count(*),0) from YourTableNameHere`

2) In your code, use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

```
var result = cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
lblCount.Text = result.ToString();
```

**Edit 2**

You want to keep track of number of records inserted in current `session`. Use `viewstate` or `session`, depending on your requirement to save counter for `session` Or only untill user stays on current page.

```
var recordsAdded = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(Session[“counter”] == null)
{
   Session[“counter”] = 0;
}

if(recordsAdded>0)
{

    Session[“counter”] = Convert.ToInteger(Session[“counter”]) + 1;
}
lblCount.Text = Session[“counter”];
```

Above will keep track of inserted records in session

Comment: is it possible to just give an example re the max; how does max comes in when i should be counting.

Comment: if it runs more than run time the result is still one

Comment: so how could I change it from that to allow it to increment

Comment: it is really when i'm inserting i would like to count

Comment: i don't want all the records in the table. for example the user enters 1111 as id then count be 1 then the  user enters 1234 count would be two. isn't that possible

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("selectId", conn);
this is checking if the id exist

Comment: I edited answer. If this is not what you want, I will read your question again. Please see and mention all details in question

Comment: SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("CreateUserId", con);this an insert into query so i should add this in there Select Isnull(count(*),0)

Comment: this still returning one

Comment: You just want to increment counter by 1 for number of records entered then you need to use some global variable (for WinForms) or Session for webforms. What are you using? Your question is tagged as winforms and asp.net too

Comment: Then remove the select query added after insert and use the edit2 from answer. This should help